# Why does textarea render but AutosizeTextarea with the same parameters leads to an Invariant Violation exception?

Tags: reactjs

I have a working `textarea` in React for which I would like to modify the rows attribute. This is the text area:

```
   <textarea
        style={{width: '100%'}}
        type="text"
        value={this.state.description}
        onChange={this.changeDescription}
    />
```

Setting `rows={x}` works.

But now I would like it to grow as I type. Instead of writing my own solution, I tried to use `var AutosizeTextarea = require('react-textarea-autosize');`

Interestingly, even though I pass the same parameters in at the begining (which according to the documentation) the Component should accept these as these are used in the [example](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-textarea-autosize/blob/master/example/index.js)

However, when I use this in my JSX like this:

```
<AutosizeTextarea
    style={{width: '100%'}}
    value={this.state.description}
    onChange={this.changeDescription}
/>
```

I get the following errors:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
ReactClass (for composite components).
Check the render method of `NewProblemPageContainer`.

Debug: internal, implementation, error
Invariant Violation: Uncaught error: Element type is invalid:
expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function
(for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of `NewProblemPageContainer`.
```

I'm really confused by this error because I do:

```
 componentWillMount = () => {
    this.setState({
     description: '',
    });
 }
```

AND the `onChange` parameter is a function:

```
changeDescription = (event) => {
    this.setState({
            description: event.target.value
    });
};
```

What do I need to change on this component (whose addition causes the exception to occur) when both of the parameters I am passing meet the conditions which the error says I don't: **expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.**

I wouldn't understand how this changes my `render()` method at large, so if it has to do with that, pleas explain! I'm in over my head,

Answer (score 1):

Likely you don't need this now, but for anyone finding this after getting the same error, see:

https://github.com/andreypopp/react-textarea-autosize/issues/98

You need to use either

`var AutosizeTextarea = require('react-textarea-autosize').default;`

if using CommonJS require syntax, or

`import AutosizeTextarea from 'react-textarea-autosize';`

if using ES6 import syntax.